# Why is pointwise stabilizer of a reflecting hyperplane a cyclic group?

Tags: proof-writing, cyclic-groups, reflection-group

> Let $G$ be a pseudoreflection group and $H$ be a reflecting hyperplane. Let $G_H$ be the subgroup of $G$ consisting of all those elements of $G$ which stabilize the reflecting hyperplane $H$ pointwise. Show that $G_H$ is a cyclic subgroup of $G.$

Today while going through a paper I found this interesting claim which I can't able to prove. What is a generator of $G_H$? Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.